# how should arguments be set to get the showProxyConfig pop up when executing a installer made in install4j?

Tags: proxy, install4j

I'm trying to get the 'Proxy selection and authentication' pop up from mentioned in this document https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/v/8.0/help/doc/installers/http.html because I need to enter the Proxy settings during the installation of my app in Linux. I'm using install4j v10.

In my installer I have a 'Display progress' screen and in it a 'Download file' action.

I'm trying to trigger it by adding -Dinstall4j.showProxyConfig=true as argument in the installer. I tried it on Windows by adding the arg in the 'Arguments' property under 'Execution Option' in the 'Installer' Properties section. Also, I tried in the terminal like this:

C:\MyCurrentPath>MyInstallerName.exe -Dinstall4j.showProxyConfig=true

And in Linux like this:

session>bash MyInstallerName.sh -Dinstall4j.showProxyConfig=true

But non of the three ways work. Am I missing something? should the arguments have other format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using install4j v10

Proxy handling has been reimplemented in install4j 9 and the proxy dialog is no longer available since then. For install4j v10 please see

https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/installers/http.html

Comment: Thanks Ingo! I was consulting old documentation. It worked with the new commands like this (just for anybody else reference): bash MyApp.sh -Dhttps.proxyHost=<myproxyhost> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<myproxyport>